# do local clifford gates preserve code distance?

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-code, clifford-group

It can be shown that
[clifford gates do not preserve distance](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32018/do-clifford-gates-preserve-distance).

My question is what if you restrict to ***local*** clifford gates, is distance preserved by these?

(by local I mean that they act on each qubit individually; so tensor product of single qubit gates).

(my guess is that they do not but it will be good to see a proof or reference)

Comment: All local unitaries, Clifford or not, on any code, stabilizer or not, preserve distance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since local Cliffords (LC) do not change the weight of a Pauli operator, the distance of two LC-equivalent stabilizer codes is the same.

As a remark: Any stabilizer code is also LC-equivalent to a graph code. In fact, LC-equivalence of stabilizer codes can be reduced to checking equivalences of graphs by *local complementation* ([Schlingemann](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0111080), [van den Nest et al.](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevA.70.034302)).

Comment: nice argument using weights...I'm not too familiar with the graph code form and the (first) paper looks hard to digest but I'll try.

Comment: @unknown I think the second one is a bit simpler to understand. Anyway, it was just a remark in case you want to check LC-equivalence or you like graphs.

Comment: I did some more testing and ran across this potential discrepancy : for $$G=[[-1+\imath,-1+\imath],[1+\imath,-1-\imath]]/2$$ it is clifford but maps $X \to -\imath X Z$  and $Z \to X$ so it wouldn't preserve weights. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: @unknown $-iXZ=-Y$ so it has weight 1

Comment: yes of course...thanks for the clarification